# Android Soap Web service Error behind Proxy Server

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I have written a program for communicating with a web service and get response value. But when  i debug the programme i end with requestDump=null at the line `androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);` Can some one tell me the reason for the error and what can i do for this

```
public class WebService extends Activity {
       private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
       private final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
       private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
       private final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    String celsius;
    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    EditText et;
    String res,resultval;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_service);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Result);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //String result=getFarenheit(et.getText().toString());
            //tv.setText(result+"°F");
            new service().execute();
            }
        });
    }
    private class service extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
             celsius=et.getText().toString();
            SoapObject request= new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo celsuiusPI= new PropertyInfo();
            celsuiusPI.setName("Celsius");
            celsuiusPI.setValue(celsius);
            celsuiusPI.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty("XMLMarks",celsuiusPI);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope (SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.implicitTypes = true;
            envelope.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC2003;
            envelope.xsd = SoapEnvelope.XSD;
            envelope.xsi = SoapEnvelope.XSI;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
            SoapPrimitive response; 

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try{
                androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                String dump= androidHttpTransport.requestDump.toString();
                response=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                Toast.makeText(WebService.this, response.toString(), 20).show();
                Log.i("WebService output", response.toString());
                System.out.println("WebService Response"+response.toString());
                Object res= response.toString();
                resultval=(String) res;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return res;

        }
         protected void onPostExecute(String h){
             String result=h;

                tv.setText(result+"°F");

    }


}
}
```

Comment: what you do with the  androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");   There is no need of doing it. SOAP just give responce to you. You dont have to parse it from the xml structure.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your service AsyncTask with this new one and see result:

code:

```
private class service extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        System.out.println("In DoIn Background");

        // Initialize soap request + add parameters
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        // Use this to add parameters
        request.addProperty("Celsius", txtCel.getText().toString());

        // Declare the version of the SOAP request
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        try {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

            if (result != null) {
                // Get the first property and change the label text
                // txtFar.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
                res = result.getProperty(0).toString();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return res;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String h) {
        String result = h;

        tv.setText(result + "°F");

    }

}
```

Comment: STILL i get null'F as result  the thing is iam on proxy requestDump is null. How to add proxy to HTTPTransportSE

Comment: Have you just copy paste above code and run the project Or have done anything more in app ?? As because i can run it here successfully.

Comment: So hope you got answer.  You can also upvote it. So it can help others.

Comment: Copy pasted the project but still end up with same error,how to give proxy with HTTPTransportSE

Comment: iDroid Explorer do u have any solutions

Comment: why you want to give proxy as original code is working perfect.

Comment: I am doing this project on a corporate company's server hence my proxy server doesnt allow to send request,thats the reason why iam asking the doubt here

Comment: It is possible with own server or any corporate server. I have tested it. You just have to configure or make same web service at that server location and give path to that server. Then you can achieve the same goal.

Comment: My proxy is blocking the request,i need to set the proxy values to HTTPTtransportSE,Please help on this

Comment: iDroid Explorer any solution for thus sur